# How can I write a concise and complete question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

So I go a downvote on [a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/768202/) which I suspect is related to the comment:

> "You haven't really demonstrated a problem here, and it looks like there's a lot more information than needed to set up what you're asking. You might want to try rephrasing your question"

I've tried to provide links as well as a solution. How can I improve the question and yet be concise? Any thoughts and feedback would be welcome.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask